# Bash string comparison w/ leading zeros

Tags: regex, bash

Just wondered if there was a simple way in bash scripting to use the 'test' construct to compare two strings matching a given pattern. In this particular case, I want a pair of numeric strings to match if they have leading zeros in front of either of them. Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

STR1=123
STR2=00123

if [[ "0*${STR1}" == "0*${STR2}" ]]; then
    echo "Strings are equal"
else
    echo "Strings are NOT equal"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Just a technicality: `[[` isn't `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure your strings are *numeric*, then you should use `-eq` instead of `==`:

```
if [ $string1 -eq $string2 ]
then
    echo "These are equal"
fi
```

The `-eq` doesn't care about leading zeros

The problem is that if neither string is numeric (or one string is equal to zero and the other isn't numeric), this will still work:

```
string1=foo
string2=bar
if [ $string1 -eq $string2 ]
then
    echo "These are equal"  # This will print, and it shouldn't!
fi
```

The only way I see getting around this issue is to do something like this:

```
if expr $string1 + 0 > /dev/null 2&1 && expr $string2 + 0 > /dev/null 2>&1
then  # Both strings are numeric!
    if [ $string1 -eq $string2 ]
    then
        echo "Both strings are numeric and equal."
    else
        echo "Both strings are numeric, but not equal."
elif [ $sring1 = $sring2 ]
then
    echo "Strings aren't numeric, but are the same
else
    echo "Strings aren't numeric or equal to each other"
fi
```

The `expr` will return a non-zero exit code if the string isn't numeric. I can use this in my `if` to test to see if my strings are in fact numeric or not.

If they are both numeric, I can use my second `if` with the `-eq` to test for integer equivalency. Leading zeros are no problem.

The `elif` is used in case my strings are not numeric. In that case, I test with `=` which tests string equivalency.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the route I ended up going. 99% of the time, they will be all numeric. In the rare instances there are any letters, I use tr to strip them all out. I also use -z to check if it's null beforehand too.

Answer (score 3):

Strip any leading zeros from the strings, then check if the results are equal. This solution requires extended pattern support from `bash`.

```
shopt -s extglob
if [[ "${STR1##*(0)}" = "${STR2##*(0)}" ]]; then
   echo "Strings are equal"
fi
```

You can also use `bash`'s built-in regular expression support, but it might require two comparisons if you don't know which string has more leading 0s. The test works when the string on the left has at least as many leading 0s as the string on the right.

```
if [[ $STR1 =~ 0*$STR2 || $STR2 =~ 0*$STR1 ]]; then
    echo "Strings are equal"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would make:

```
#!/bin/bash

STR1=123
STR2=00123

if [ `echo -n ${STR1} | sed 's/^0*//g'` == `echo -n ${STR2} | sed 's/^0*//g'` ]; then
    echo "Strings are equal"
else
    echo "Strings are NOT equal"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: I don't know sed but, `s/^0*//g` will only match once because of the BOL anchor, but it will always match because of the *, and the `g` modifier is useless. Maybe thats a filter to sed that it does match.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious and trivial solution is to explicitly indicate the base of the numbers. Then any leading zeros are insignificant because the  numbers will not be interpreted as octal.

```
if [[ 10#$STR1 -eq 10#$STR2 ]]; then
    echo "Numbers are equal"
else
    echo "Numbers are NOT equal"
fi
```

Notice also the switch to `-eq` for numeric comparison.

Comment: Good bash solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `expr` to convert the strings into numeric values. Note an alternative bash method - double parentheses - does NOT work as values with leading zeroes are parsed as octal values. e.g.

```
STR1=000123
echo $(($STR1))  # outputs 83
```

SOLUTION

```
#!/bin/bash
STR1="00123"
STR2="0000123"

n1=$(expr $STR1 + 0)
n2=$(expr $STR2 + 0)
if [ $n1 -eq $n2 ];then
    echo "Strings are equal"
else
    echo "Strings are NOT equal"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Just right. Normally $(( expr )) is the way to go, unless you need octal.

Comment: Arithmetic expressions work fine if you take a simple precaution: specify the number's base: `STR1=0789; n1=$(( 10#$STR1 ))`

Comment: If you're using `-eq`, there's no need to do any fancy stuff to the two strings. The `-eq` is a ***numeric*** comparison and will ignore leading zeros.